# K-means on hadoop compile error...

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, k-means

I've downloaded the k-means(in hadoop mapreduce) opensource. But, it has compile errors.

---------------------SOURCE----------------------------

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012
 * Parallel and Distributed Systems Group (PVS)
 * Institute of Computer Science (IFI)
 * Heidelberg University
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package examples;

import algorithms.kmeans.Cluster;
import algorithms.kmeans.Clusters;
import algorithms.kmeans.SamplesCache;
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVectorWritable;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class KMeansHadoop {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KMeansHadoop.class);

    public static class KMeansMapper extends
            MRMapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Clusters, Clusters> {

        private SamplesCache cache = new SamplesCache(500);
        private int cacheSize = 10000;
        private Clusters clusters = null;
        private int k = 0;
        private int nextCentroidToInit = 0;

        /**
         * Configures the mapper by reading two configuration options:
         *  - "numClusters": the k in k-Means
         *  - "numAuxClusters": the number of in-memory auxiliary clusters representing the input data
         *
         * @param context the mapper context, used to access the configuration
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super.setup(context);
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            this.k = conf.getInt("numCluster", 5);
            this.clusters = new Clusters(k);
            this.cacheSize = conf.getInt("numAuxCluster", 500);
            this.cache = new SamplesCache(cacheSize);
        }

        /**
         * Maps the input lines to initial centroids and, as a side-effect, stores auxiliary clusters representing the
         * input data in memory
         *
         * @param key the key provided by the input format, not used here
         * @param value one line of the input; input format: one data point per line, vector components delimited by spaces
         * @param context the mapper context used to send initial centroids to the reducer
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

             // Input format: one data point per line, components delimited by spaces
            final List<Double> doubleValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
            final StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while(tk.hasMoreElements()) {
                final String token = tk.nextToken();
                doubleValues.add(Double.parseDouble(token));
            }

            double[] dv = new double[doubleValues.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<doubleValues.size(); i++) {
                dv[i] = doubleValues.get(i);
            }
            DenseVector dvec = new DenseVector(dv);
            DenseVectorWritable sample = new DenseVectorWritable(dvec);

            // add sample to local auxiliary clusters
            this.cache.addSample(sample);

            // first k points are chosen as initial centroids
            if (nextCentroidToInit < k) {
                this.clusters.set(nextCentroidToInit, new Cluster(sample, sample));
                this.nextCentroidToInit += 1;
            } else if (nextCentroidToInit == k) {
                // send initial centroids to reducer
                context.write(new IntWritable(0), this.clusters);
                this.nextCentroidToInit += 1;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Remaps the input data when a new set of preliminary clusters is received from the reducer by recalculating
         * the assignment of the local input data, as represented by the auxiliary clusters, to the preliminary clusters
         * and sends the updated centroids to the reducer.
         * @param cs the preliminary clusters computed by the reducer
         * @param context the mapper context used to send the locally recomputed centroids to the reducer
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
        public void remap(List<Clusters> cs, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            LOG.info("Remapping preliminary clusters");
            // set the preliminary clusters as new clusters
            this.clusters = cs.get(0).clone();
            this.clusters.reset();
            // reassign the local input data, represented by the auxiliary clusters, to the clusters, thereby readjusting
            // the clusters centroids
            this.cache.reAssignAll(clusters);
            // send the locally updated clusters to the reducer
            context.write(new IntWritable(0), this.clusters);
        }
    }

    public static class KMeansReducer extends
            MRReducer<IntWritable, Clusters, IntWritable, Clusters, Clusters> {

        private double lastError = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        private float epsilon = Float.MAX_VALUE;

        /**
         * Configures the mapper by reading the configuration option "epsilon": The minimum change of the MSE needed to
         * trigger a new iteration.
         *
         * @param context the reducer context, used to access the configuration
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            epsilon = conf.getFloat("epsilon", 100f);
        }

        /**
         * Reduces a list of clusters locally computed by the mappers into a preliminary global set of clusters, which
         * is then restreamed to the mappers, or, iff the MSE of the global set of clusters has not changed by more than
         * epsilon since the last reduce invocation ends the iteration by emiting the final set of clusters.
         *
         * @param key the key set by the mapper, not used here
         * @param values the list of locally computed clusters computed by the mappers
         * @param context the reducer context, used to restream preliminary clusters to the mappers and emit the final
         *                clusters
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
        @Override
        protected void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Clusters> values,
                              MRReduceContext<IntWritable, Clusters, IntWritable, Clusters, Clusters> context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // Merge the list of clusters into one set of clusters
            Clusters results = null;
            for(Clusters clusters : values) {
                if( results == null ) {
                    results = clusters;
                } else {
                    results.merge(clusters);
                }
            }

            Double error = results.getMSE();

            LOG.info("Last error " + lastError + ", current error " + error);

            if (lastError < Double.MAX_VALUE &&
                    error <= lastError + epsilon &&
                    error >= lastError - epsilon) {
                // MSE has changed by less than epsilon: Emit final result
                context.write(new IntWritable(0), results);
                LOG.info("Final result written.");
            } else {
                // MSE has changed by more than epsilon: Send recomputed preliminary clusters to mappers to start a new
                // iteration
                this.lastError = error;
                results.computeNewCentroids();
                context.restream(results);
                LOG.info("Preliminary result restreamed.");
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Executes the streaming Hadoop MapReduce program
     * @param args first arg is input path, second arg is output path
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.setBoolean("mrstreamer.hadoop.streaming", true);

        // has to be 1 to ensure the algorithm producing valid results
        conf.setInt(JobContext.NUM_REDUCES, 1);

        conf.setInt(JobContext.NUM_MAPS, 4);

        conf.set("numCluster", "5");
        conf.set("numAuxCluster", "500");

        Job job = new MRSJob(conf, "kmeanshadoop");

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Clusters.class);

        job.setMapperClass(KMeansMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(KMeansReducer.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

}
```

---

---------------------------ERROR------------------------------

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
NUM_REDUCES cannot be resolved or is not a field
NUM_MAPS cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

### at examples.KMeansHadoop.main(KMeansHadoop.java:222)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are not using the same version of Hadoop as the authors of this code. It should be covered by the line:

`import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobContext;`

Update to hadoop version 2.2.0 (or later) if you want to use these settings.

Otherwise, you can use instead of these two commands, the following on the old API:

```
conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
conf.setNumMapTasks(4); //but this is only a suggestion to hadoop
```